# fwrite doesn't fail when disk is full?

Tags: glibc, fwrite, tmpfs

here is a test program I wrote

```
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
  const char name[1024] = "/dev/shm/test_file";
  off_t len = atol(argv[argc - 1]);
  char buf[1024];
  FILE * f = fopen(name, "w");
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    int ret = fwrite(buf, 1024, 1, f);
    if (ret != 1) {
      printf("disk full\n");
    }
  }
  if ( fclose(f) != 0)
    printf("failed to close\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to fill the /dev/shm to almost full

```
tmpfs            36G   36G   92K 100% /dev/shm
```

and ran

```
$ ./a.out 93
failed to close
```

my glibc

```
$ /lib/libc.so.6 
GNU C Library stable release version 2.12, by Roland McGrath et al.
```

the kernel version is 2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64

I understand that this behavior is caused by fwrite try to cache the data in memory. (I tried setvbuf(NULL...) and fwrite immediately return failure). But this seems a little different from the definition

> The fwrite() function shall return the number of elements successfully
>   written, which may be less than nitems if a write error is
>   encountered. If size or nitems is 0, fwrite() shall return 0 and the
>   state of the stream remains unchanged. Otherwise, if a write error
>   occurs, the error indicator for the stream shall be set, [CX] [Option
>   Start]  and errno shall be set to indicate the error. [Option End]

The data was not successfully written to disk however its return value is 1. no errno set.
In this test case, the fclose catch the failure. But it could be caught by even a ftell function which is quite confusing.

I am wondering if this happens to all versions of glibc and would this be consider a bug.

Answer (score 0):

> The data was not successfully written to disk

The standard doesn't talk about the disk. It talks about data being successfully written to the *stream* (which it has been).

> I am wondering if this happens to all versions of glibc

Most likely.

> and would this be consider a bug.

It's a bug in your interpretation of the requirements on `fwrite`.